# Разбить строку результата на две в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите решение вот такой вот смарт-задачки: имеем результат выборки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате появляется строка, где в двух колонках и FixHours, и AddHours есть значения не равные нулю:

FixHours = **0,5** AddHours = **1,5** CalculatedValue = 16.5

Как ее можно разделить на две, чтобы получить строки:

FixHours = **0,5** AddHours = **0** CalculatedValue = 16.5

FixHours = **0** AddHours = **1,5** CalculatedValue = 16.5

Была идея находить только эту строку, затем искусственно создавать вторую с помощью Union. Но она провалилась, т.к. такие строки в таблице встречаются не один раз. В общем, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если порядок не важен, то:

```
WITH SourceData AS (
    SELECT FixHours, AddHours, CalculatedValue FROM SomeTable --тут ваша выборка
) 
SELECT FixHours, 0, CalculatedValue FROM SourceData
WHERE FixHours <> 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0, AddHours, CalculatedValue FROM SourceData
WHERE AddHours <> 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0, 0, CalculatedValue FROM SourceData
WHERE FixHours = 0 AND AddHours = 0
```

Если важен - то нужно добавлять `rownumber` в SourceData, и сортировать результат `union` по нему.

Comment: В этом варианте в результат не попадают строки, где и FixHours и AddHours одновременно равны нулю. Кто знает, вдруг в выборке окажутся и такие?

Comment: @Yaant ок, согласен. дописал (правда тогда ответ ничем от вашего не отличается почти, кроме форматирования :)

Answer (score 2):

Если есть желание без всяких юнионов, можно сделать join на таблицу, которая возвращает 2 записи и дальше уже по условиям выбирать, что показывать.

Т.е. что-нибудь вроде такого варианта (не тестировал, но должно работать, за производительность такого решения также не ручаюсь):

```
select case spt.number when 0 then t.FixHours else 0 end as FixHours, 
    case spt.number when 1 then t.AddHours else 0 end as AddHours, 
    t.CalculatedValue
from table t
join master..spt_values spt on spt.type='p' and spt.number in (0,1) and 
    ((t.FixHour > 0 and spt.number = 0) or (t.AddHours > 0 and spt.number = 1) or (t.FixHour = 0 and t.AddHours = 0 and spt.number = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select fixhours,0,calculatevalue
  from a 
 where a.fixhours!=0 and a.addhours!=0

union 

select 0 ,addhours, calculatevalue
  from a 
 where a.fixhours!=0 and a.addhours!=0
```

[Пример решения](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e4be/1)

Comment: Хорошая идея. Надо попробовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
;WITH cte (FixHours, AddHours, CalculatedValue) AS ( -- тут должен быть запрос, возвращающий исходную таблицу
SELECT 10, 0, 14
UNION ALL SELECT 0.5, 0, 14.5
UNION ALL SELECT 0.5, 1.5, 16.5
UNION ALL SELECT 0, 0.5, 17
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 0.75, 17.75
UNION ALL SELECT 0, 2, 19.75
)
SELECT FixHours, AddHours, CalculatedValue FROM cte WHERE FixHours = 0 OR AddHours = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT FixHours, 0, CalculatedValue FROM cte WHERE FixHours <> 0 AND AddHours <> 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0, AddHours, CalculatedValue FROM cte WHERE FixHours <> 0 AND AddHours <> 0
ORDER BY CalculatedValue -- ну или какой там требуется быть порядок
```